# Container overflows the page (React)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, containers, jsx

New to React. I wish to make the page grow and scrollable as the container gets bigger. But now the container overflows at the top, although I can scroll to see the bottom part.

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-haze-4dnb7?file=/src/App.js

In this sandbox, the back button at the top overflows the page. If I add one more `{test}`, the button will be gone. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: i added lots of {test}, back button is still there.

Comment: Your issue is still not clear. 
Could you please explain more for a good answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You trying to ask to fix the Back button on the top.
You can do that by giving your  row, a className

```
<Row className="pb-4 header">
            <Button className="mt-4 letter" variant="outline-light">
              {"< Back"}
            </Button>
          </Row>
```

and set its property to

```
.header{
position:fixed;
}
```

[image: please check screenshot after adding for of {test}]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. My issue is that if you add more `{test}` to it, even if you scroll to the top, you can't see the button any more. The container seems to be out of the page. Idk why that happens even though I already set the overflow to auto.

Comment: There is some issue with your browser, my friend. 

It is perfectly working on all my devices . 
I have added many `{test}` in it

Comment: please check screenshot after adding for of `{test}` . I have edited my answer. Check the Screenshot

Comment: Okay, that's bc my App.css got somehow removed, so the problem must be in my css... I removed the `position: fixed` line in my original css and it worked lmao. Thanks man

Comment: That's what we are here for. ☺